# How do not remove static import in test in Intellij IDea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import

There is an option `Optimize imports on fly` (Editor->General->AutoImport) which removes unused imports. But when a Test class is created, Intellij idea add `import static org.junit.Assert.*;` to it. But when the file is saved (just after added) it removes this import. Is there a way to set up IntelliJ idea for preventing that, but keep `Optimize imports on fly` enabled?

Comment: Not really, no, and import * is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Bad, **but** not for test code, and imports like `org.junit.assert` or `Mockito`. ;)

Comment: Maybe there is a file template which adds the "import static org.junit.Assert.*;"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a setting for your exact case, but:

There is a Setting `Editor > Code Style > Java | Use Import with *`

You can then set `import static org.Junit.Assert.*;`